# Как добавить новый document.title = "Новое сообщение!" когда приходит новое сообщение?

Tags: php, sql, ajax

У меня в чате сделано оповещение конкретному юзеру на JS. Звук реагирует на изменение id в базе и цифры выводятся в самом верху. Хочу, чтобы со звуком менялся title, например когда юзер свернул вкладку, или находится в другом окне. пробовал добавить

```
var content = document.getElementById('content').value;
document.title = content;
```

Но не хочет работать с этим кодом:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<audio id="audio-new-message" src="notify.ogg"  ></audio>
<a id="content"></a> 
<script>

var old_html = "";
 function show()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "new_message.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            if (html != old_html) {
                
                $("#content").html(old_html = html);
                var audio = $("#audio-new-message")[0];
                audio.currentTime = 0;
                audio.play();
 
            }
        }
    });
}
  
$(document).ready(function(){  
            show();  
            setInterval('show()',5000);  
        }); 
var content = document.getElementById('content').value;
document.title = content;
```

Comment: а что значит "не хочет работать"? ничего не меняется, крашится, выводит не то, перезагружается машина.  Хотя не удивительно - звук проигрывается в колбеке, а title меняете не понятно где. Перетащите эти строки внутрь колбека и похоже все заработает

Comment: А можно по подробне? И будет ли меняться, обратно, когда юзер вернулся на страничку?

Comment: будет ли меняется? если напишите код - будет меняться. Не напишите - нет.